# Cypress cannot find an element inside form and the form is inside an iframe

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

```
<div id="p">
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="col1">
            <div id="ca">
                <iframe id="frame"> // I already got this in the code
                    <#document>
                        <html>
                            <body>
                                <form id="form">
                                    <input name="name"> // THIS IS WHERE I WANTED TO GET
                                </form>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        </div>
        <div class="col3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
cy.get('iframe')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
  .should('be.visible')
  .then(cy.wrap)
  .find('input[name="name"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .type('myUsername');
```

I tried this but it can only find the iframe but not the input field inside the form. I also tried finding the form first but same result.

Comment: to add to my post, i tried several approach but same results, it can only see the iframe and beyond that the form inside the iframe which inside the html body is not visible

Comment: On 10.4, looks like the form is not rendered in the iframe with the sample you gave.

Comment: @LolaIchingbola. yeah i checked the test-url structure on its iframe, its similar but when at the moment I am trying to work it out those sample solutions

Comment: The principle is to retry the whole chain from `get('iframe')` to `find('input[name="name"])` - often the iframe can be initially visible but then reset itself as the inner page loads up. What you have will be flaky in that situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try out this:

```
    cy.visit("page to be visited");
    ****Here this wait should be dynamic as some iframe with large content may take time to load so make sure the iframe is loaded properly, Test will fail if it is not loaded.****  
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.get("#frame")
      .its("0.contentDocument")
      .its("body")
      .find("#form")
      .find("input[name='name']")
      .type("Cypress");
```

I've tested this solution and it worked fine at my end.

Also make sure to update cypress.config.js file with :

```
chromeWebSecurity: false,
```

As a chrome security issue.

For more info, Please check this blog:
**https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-handle-iframes-in-cypress/**

Here is a snap of it's working:

[image]